# About density in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u$ in $L^2(-L,L)$.  Does exist a sequence $\{ u_n\}$ in $H^3_0(-L, L)$ such that $$\|u_n  \|_{ H^3_0(-L, L)} < C$$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\|u_n - u \|_{ L^2(-L, L)} =0$$
for some positive constant $C$?

Comment: did you look at $u_n \in H^1_0$ first ? and you are asking if for any $u \in L^2$, there always exists a sequence $\{u_n\}$ ?

Comment: question : how would you approximate (in the $\|.\|_{L^2}$ sense) a step by some function whose derivative has a bounded $\|.\|_{L^2}$ norm ?

Comment: It is with $H^3_0$, the question is if for $u \in L^2$,  there exists a sequence in $H^3_0$ satisfying the above properties.

Comment: Yes,  I would to know if it is possible approximate function in $L^2$ by a sequence bounded in $H^3_0$

Comment: as I wrote, is it possible with $u_n \in H^1$ if $u$ is a step function ?

Comment: I guess that this question has a positive answer in $L^2(R)$,  it mean,  when the domain is the whole space.  I would like to know what happen in a bounded domain

Comment: it is impossible to approximate a step function by such a sequence $\in H^1$. it is possible only if $u' \in L^2$. in the same way, it is impossible to approximate $u \in L^2$ by such a (bounded) sequence in $H^3$, except if $u''' \in L^2$

Comment: It is possible to approximate a step function $L^2$ by a sequence in $H^1$, but,  I don't sure that this sequence can  be bounded with the norm $H^1$.  Recall that the embedding $H^s \subset L^2$ is dense

Comment: that's why I told you to consider the case $u(x) = 1_{x \in [0,L]}$ you can see that an approximating sequence will be unbounded in $H^1([-L,L])$

Comment: all this tells you that when $s \ge 1$, even if $H^s(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$ , the unit open ball of $H^s(\Omega)$ is not dense in any open ball of $L^2(\Omega)$ (and the unit open ball of $H^s_0(\Omega)$ being dense in the unit open ball of $H^s(\Omega)$, the result is the same for $H^s_0(\Omega)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible: Assume that it is possible. Then, since $H_0^3(-L,L)$ is a Hilbert space, you have (for a subsequence) $u_n \rightharpoonup v$ in $H_0^3(-L,L)$ for some $v \in H_0^3(-L,L)$. Thus, $u = v \in H_0^3(-L,L)$, but this is obviously not true for all $u \in L^2(-L,L)$.

Comment: you meant $H^3(-L,L)$ is a Hilbert space, not $H^3_0(-L,L)$ ?

Comment: Both, $H^3(-L,L)$ and $H_0^3(-L,L)$ are Hilbert spaces. And the question was about $H_0^3(-L,L)$.

Comment: yes but it is much more simpler to consider $H^3(\Omega)$ than $H^3_0(\Omega)$, at least when $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and has a weird shape. hence I think the simplest proof is with $H^3(\Omega)$, and only mentioning that once it is proven that $H^3_0(\Omega)$ is also a closed/complete inner product space (a Hilbert space), one can replace $H^3(\Omega)$ by $H^3_0(\Omega)$.